# Dask doesn't appear to take advantage of Cores/CPU

Tags: python, delay, dask

I'm considering dask for a project.  I have a large 3GB csv file with 50,000 variables and 60,000 records.  I won't know what fields I need until runtime.  I need to apply a function a million times to the dataset.  I've used dask delayed to apply the functions in a quick manner.  However, when I use Compute to get the results back, processing time is very slow.  Am I expecting too much from dask?  Or is there something I can do to the compute loop to speed up processing.  Thanks for any guidance or help you can provide. See program below.  I'm most concerned with the `results = compute(answers)` line.

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask import compute, delayed
import time
start_time = time.time()
dask.set_options(get=dask.threaded.get)

def get_base(input):
  return df['unwtd'].sum()

df = dd.read_csv("*.csv", sep="|", quoting=3, encoding = "utf_8", dtype = 'object', error_bad_lines=False, sample=(10000000))

df['unwtd']=1.0
df['Total'] = "_1"

values = [delayed(get_base)(x) for x in range(2)]


print("Getting Answers %s" % (time.time() - start_time))
answers = compute(*values, get=dask.threaded.get)


print("Getting Results %s" % (time.time() - start_time))
results = compute(answers)
print(results)
print("Done")
print("Total seconds %s " % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: The GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) is a bad thing.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Not [necessarily](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186889/why-was-python-written-with-the-gil) it has its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @user204548 Have you tried using `dask.multiprocessing.get`?

Comment: This is where things get strange for me.  Dask.dataframe is inherently multi-threaded.  How do I set things up so that dask.dataframe can take advantage of multiprocesses?

Comment: I thought dask and the GIL somehow worked together.  Is there a way to configure the python environment so it does?